# How to define Chern classes on complex analytic spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, chern-classes

Let $X$ be a complex analytic space, assume normal if needed, and $\mathscr F$ be a coherent sheaf. How to define Chern classes $c_i(\mathscr F)$? Do the usual Chern class axioms hold in this case? Is there any reference?

Edit: If the answer is no in general, under which assumption could we define it?

Comment: This is a classical problem, which has been studied by a number of authors. For Chern classes in $H^*(X,\Bbb{Z}$, this is done in H. Green's thesis, see : D. Toledo, Y. Tong, *Green’theory of Chern classes and the Riemann-Roch formula*, Contemp. Math., 58-I, (1986), 261–275. For more refined classes in Deligne's cohomology, see J. Grivaux, *Chern classes in Deligne cohomology for coherent analytic sheaves*,
Math. Ann. 347 (2010), no. 2, 249-284.

Comment: Moreover, they are defined for perfect complexes.

Comment: @abx In those references, $X$ is assumed to be a complex manifold, while the question is for complex analytic spaces. As far as I can tell, the smoothness of $X$ seems to be essential since the construction of Green relies on local exactness of the de Rham complex of smooth forms.

Comment: @Richard Lärkäng: You are right, I didn't read the question carefully enough. I leave my comment since the references might be useful anyway.

Comment: I agree that the references might be useful, and they are the closest to answering the question that I am aware of. I could also imagine that Green's construction might yield classes in de Rham cohomology also in the singular case, although due to lack of exactness one wouldn't be able to interpret them as sheaf cohomology classes.

Comment: I don't know a construction of Chern classes of coherent sheaves even for a (non-smooth) _algebraic_ scheme. @ZM, coherent sheaves are not perfect complexes over singular spaces.

Comment: With the hypotheses as stated, I do not see how you would define the Chern classes even if you assume that $X$ is also a complex algebraic variety.  As Z. M. notes, the usual hypothesis for existence of Chern classes is that the coherent sheaf is "perfect", i.e., it locally has finite free resolutions.  Plenty of coherent sheaves on singular algebraic varieties are not perfect.

Comment: @RichardLärkäng I'm not familiar with de Rham cohomology on analytic space. What's the difference when $X$ is singular?

Comment: I meant that you take an appropriate definition of smooth forms, and then consider d-closed forms modulo d-exact ones. However, I realize now that I was too optimistic. The construction of Green also relies on the fact that coherent sheaves on a manifold locally have finite free resolutions, which as commented on above is not true in the singular case.